# Negative binomial modelling versus transformed linear modeling

Tags: r, data-transformation, linear-model, random-effects-model, negative-binomial-distribution

My dataset (Data) contains data on distance traveled by an organism (Distance) based on their genotype (the two genotypes are A and B). For each genotype, there are 3 replicate genetic lines (A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3), but the replicate lines from each genotype are not related (i.e. A1 does not correspond in anyway to B1). I want to determine if there is a difference in distance traveled across genotypes. The purpose of the replicate lines for each genotype is to make sure that any genotype-related difference in Distance found is a result of the genotype itself and not just other variation occurring in the lab populations of genotype A and genotype B. So, basically, I would want to see if the effect of genotype on distance is consistent across the replicate genetic lines.

I'm running into 2 main problems analyzing this data:
1) I don't know how to model the relationship between genotype and replicate lines. I've considered the following solutions but don't know which is correct:
- run the model with genotype as a fixed effect and line as a random effect
- run the model with genotype as a fixed effect and line nested within genotype as a random effect (in the code that looks like (1|Genotype/Line) )
- run the model with only line as a fixed effect then compare the directions of estimates to see if they correspond with genotype differences. My issue with this is that in the summary, it automatically sets one line as the basis for comparison to calculate estimates from when what I want is to compare 3 lines with the other 3 lines and see if there's a difference
- run the model with only genotype

2) My second problem is that the Distance data is not normally distributed (see picture below)

The distance data is not normally distributed.
[image: The distance data is not normally distributed.]

I have tried two possible solutions, but again, I don't know which is more appropriate/how to check which one is more appropriate:

- Because of zero-inflation and over-dispersion, it was suggested that I try modeling it in a negative binomial glmm. I used the package glmmTMB to allow for a negative binomial distribution with the following code: m.nb<-glmmTMB(Distance~Genotype+Sex+Size+Temperature+Time+(1|Genotype/Line),data=Data,family=nbinom2). Here I put in Line as a nested random effect (again not sure if that's the best way to do this).
- I also tried transforming the Distance data and sticking to linear models. I used the bestNormalize package in r which told me the best transformation was the orderNorm transformation, so I used that then put the data in linear models. The data did look normally distributed once transformed this way.
  First I tried using a linear model function that allows for random effects (lmer), and my code looked like 
  m.lmer<-lmer(Distance~Genotype+Sex+Size+Temperature+Time+(1|Genotype/Line),data=Data)
  I also tried using the lm function and excluding random effects so my code looked like
  m.lm<-lmer(Distance~Genotype+Sex+Size+Temperature+Time,data=Data)

If you have any suggestions about how to better model this data, please let me know. I'm a bit new to R and stats, so I'm sorry if what I've tried is very mistaken/sloppy. Also please let me know if including more information for this post would make it easier to provide an answer.

Comment: the negative binomial model you have should be something you can start if.. is there any issue with that?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. The normal model diagnostic plots (qqplots) for the negative binomial model looked kind of bad, but I wasn't sure if that mattered or not?

Comment: you mean a qqplot with the theoretical quantiles according to pnbinom ? It could be, the amount of zeros is throwing it off.

Comment: yeah it's a try, the nbinom might not be a good distribution for distances...If you transform it to normal, does it look ok?